# Как сделать задержку перед загрузкой уровня 3,6 ,чтоб успела проиграться hitsound

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
public class EnemyBox : MonoBehaviour{
    public AudioSource hitsound;

    void Start () {

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider boxCollider)
    {
        if(boxCollider.name == "Carr")
        {

           Application.LoadLevel("3.6");
            hitsound.Play();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html Вам поможет эта статья

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно использовать асинхронную загрузку уровня. И запихнуть это в короутину:

```
AsyncOperation _asyncSceneLoad;
IEnumerator LoadYourAsyncScene(string sceneName)
{
    _asyncSceneLoad = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName);
    _asyncSceneLoad.allowSceneActivation = false;

    // Wait until the asynchronous scene fully loads
    while (!asyncLoad.isDone)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

А когда мелодия доиграла делаешь

```
_asyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = true;
```

Можешь сделать еще одну короутину которая будет проверять что hitsound уже стопнулась. Или как-то модифицировать эту. Этой информации достаточно что бы решить задачу. :)